# Getting error while loading image in picture box c#

Tags: c#

I want to load image (stored in sql server of type image) in my windows form sometimes below code is working fine but after updating my database and after loading my form i got following error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

my code is looking as:

```
        cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_atnd_detail",conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", Login.userid);
        ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds,0,0,"vw_EmpAtnd");
        gvDetail.DataSource = ds.Tables["vw_EmpAtnd"];
        conn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            txtName.Text = dr["Employee"].ToString();
            txtNic.Text = dr["NIC"].ToString();
            txtUserName.Text = dr["UserName"].ToString();
            txtRole.Text = dr["Role"].ToString();
            byte[] Img = (byte[])dr["Pic"];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Img);
            picEmp.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            picEmp.Refresh();
            conn.Close();
            dr.Close();
        }
```

can any body mention what am i missing or what to do ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to cast a null field. That is, `pic` field may not be available for some employee records in the table. So try checking the field before casting it, something like,

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_atnd_detail",conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", Login.userid);
    ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds,0,0,"vw_EmpAtnd");
    gvDetail.DataSource = ds.Tables["vw_EmpAtnd"];
    conn.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        txtName.Text = dr["Employee"].ToString();
        txtNic.Text = dr["NIC"].ToString();
        txtUserName.Text = dr["UserName"].ToString();
        txtRole.Text = dr["Role"].ToString();
        if (!dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Pic")))
        { 
            byte[] Img = (byte[])dr["Pic"];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Img);
            picEmp.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            picEmp.Refresh();
        }
        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
    }
```

Hope this helps...